# How to pass different values to a pytest fixture (which calls a func. having arguments) using parametrization?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

I am pretty new to Pytest and going through the pytest fixtures and parametrization for API tests.

I am trying to create a fixture that creates a POST method request using a predefined function (the arguments creates POST data) and then test out the POST request data by injecting different values to each argument of that function.

Following is a fixture that calls the function:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def create_data_usage_dec():
    dec_resp = utils.data_usage_dec(dec_name="Test Dec", purpose="Test Purpose", ref_genome_ver=37, permit_imputed=False,
                                    require_phased=True, instructions="Test Instructions", use_opt_snps=True, use_req_snps=False,
                                    opt_snp_file="opt_snps.json", req_snp_file="req_snps.json")
    return dec_resp
```

In the above snippet, the the fixture is used to call a function which uses a couple of arguments whose values are assigned, and then returns the resp object.

Later if I try to use Pytest's `mark.parametrize` decorator with the fixture to test an argument's max and min limit, e.g.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('ref_genome_ver', [37, 100])
def test_ref_gen(create_data_usage_dec):
    assert create_data_usage_dec.status_code == 200
```

then the tests are not executed but the following stack trace is generated with Pytest being error out during the collection of tests:

```
Testing started at 5:20 PM ...
Launching pytest with arguments test_Genetic_Data_Distribution/test_Data_Usage_Declaration/test_GENDATA_128.py::test_ref_gen --no-header --no-summary -q in E:\gendata-tests\api-tests\tests

============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... 
test_Genetic_Data_Distribution/test_Data_Usage_Declaration/test_GENDATA_128.py:None (test_Genetic_Data_Distribution/test_Data_Usage_Declaration/test_GENDATA_128.py)
In test_ref_gen: function uses no argument 'ref_genome_ver'








collected 0 items / 1 error
ERROR: not found: E:\gendata-tests\api-tests\tests\test_Genetic_Data_Distribution\test_Data_Usage_Declaration\test_GENDATA_128.py::test_ref_gen
(no name 'E:\\gendata-tests\\api-tests\\tests\\test_Genetic_Data_Distribution\\test_Data_Usage_Declaration\\test_GENDATA_128.py::test_ref_gen' in any of [<Module test_Genetic_Data_Distribution/test_Data_Usage_Declaration/test_GENDATA_128.py>])


============================== 1 error in 0.05s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 4
```

Can someone please suggest a way to resolve this issue?

I found that some people suggested the usage of fixture argument "Indirect=True" for some similar issues posted by other users, however I am confused in how to use that as well plus whether its actually suitable for my scenario or not.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO! :)

Your issue is a common use case and hence should be resolved easily.

But first, there is a tiny bug: If you define a parameter via `pytest.mark.parameterize`, you have to use the name of the parameter in the test function call (see below).

To parameterize the fixture, you need to add a `request` object to your fixture like so:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def create_data_usage_dec(request):
    parameterized_version = request.param
    dec_resp = utils.data_usage_dec(dec_name="Test Dec", purpose="Test Purpose", ref_genome_ver=parameterized_version, permit_imputed=False,
                                    require_phased=True, instructions="Test Instructions", use_opt_snps=True, use_req_snps=False,
                                    opt_snp_file="opt_snps.json", req_snp_file="req_snps.json")
    return dec_resp
```

In your test, you can make use of this by using the `indirect` parameter.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('create_data_usage_dec', 
                         [37, 100], 
                         indirect=['create_data_usage_dec'])
def test_ref_gen(create_data_usage_dec):
    assert create_data_usage_dec.status_code == 200
```

When running the test, pytest will lookup a fixture named "ref_genome_ver" (as given in the parameterization), because you set `indirect=['create_data_usage_dec']`. If `indiret=False` (default), the parameter name ("create_data_usage_dec" in this case) would only be taken as parameter name.

The `request` object holds the test parameter (37 or 100, respectively) in the `param` variable. Then the fixture will run, using the given test parameter, and return its result. Assuming that the returned objects has a `status_code` variable, this will be checked for a 200 in the test.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for the response, the solution works however, it makes the task more lengthy this way.
However, I found out a library that works as a wrapper for the parametrization (at least in my use case).

Comment: But many thanks for the response. I highly appreciate it.